# why void isn't a real type in C# world

Tags: c#, .net, void

All the time I'm programming on C# I have this question in mind.
I see a lot of real reasons to have real void type, as let's say

- Unification Func/Actions
- Avoid generic/non-generic types like Task/Task<>
- Safely use void function when call in dynamic env and assign result

etc. But for some reason it's not implemented and we need to deal with disadvantages. I'm trying to understand the logic behind this decision.

Comment: [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) has a pretty good overview [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/131099/227265)

Comment: Pretty fair answer, but they add `Unit` in F# which is latest MS language. Looks like their views changed with time.

Comment: Hmm, no, System.Void is very much a real type.  Plays a crucial role in the metadata of a .NET assembly, stops you from using it inappropriately in generics, enables compile error CS0673 and tells the jitter exactly what to do when it needs to figure out what a method should return.  Nothing.  That you never create an instance of the type is just a logical consequence of there not being any point in ever creating nothing.

Comment: @HansPassant - System.Void is not a type... You can check in the official doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-be/library/system.void.aspx

Comment: Whether void is a "real" type or not is a hairsplitting distinction; plainly it is an exceedingly odd type no matter whether it is "real" or not. Void exists because C was designed to be a very thin abstraction over machine language for slow, memory-constrained machines; it's a holdover from that era and we're stuck with it now. A better design for modern machines, languages and architectures would be to make void a unit type with a single value - null perhaps - and thereby achieve more consistency in the type system, but we've got backwards compat constraints now.

Comment: System.Void is simply a structure. Just because it has the name void doesn't mean "void" is a data type or should be.

Comment: But if void became a type then you would not be able to use a void pointer in C, would you?? It is built for flexibility too.

Comment: As a workaround you can implement your own Unit type, see e.g. https://chtenb.dev/?page=unit-cs